# Fit chart content inside a Mat grid tile

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, echarts

In angular 16 have created a dashboard with various cards. Inside these cards I am defining various charts using Echarts. The charts don't seem to fit inside the cards, only a portion of them is visible.

Can you help me with the styling I need to apply in order for the chart to fit the mat grid tile size?

Here's the link from stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jml845?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html

[image]